# GDB not giving details at segfault cygwin

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin

So I am trying to debug a segfault in a C++ project for school. The project uses a makefile to compile. When I run the program under gdb (using cygwin) I get the segfault but when I try to use the "l" command to show the code I get different code than expected, and when I use "frame", gdb only prints the name of the function instead of the code that last executed.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000010041570b in NodeCorrectness::eval(Alignment const&) ()
(gdb) l
1       /* advapi32.cc: Win32 replacement functions.
2
3       This file is part of Cygwin.
4
5       This software is a copyrighted work licensed under the terms of the
6       Cygwin license.  Please consult the file "CYGWIN_LICENSE" for
7       details. */
8
9       #include "winsup.h"
10      #include <winioctl.h>
(gdb) frame
#0  0x000000010041570b in NodeCorrectness::eval(Alignment const&) ()
(gdb)
```

Using backtrace I get the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000042781b in NodeCorrectness::eval(Alignment const&) ()
#1  0x0000000000421a2f in MeasureCombination::printMeasures(Alignment const&, std::ostream&) const ()
#2  0x00000000004fbedf in makeReport(Graph const&, Graph&, Alignment const&, MeasureCombination const&, Method*, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
    ()
#3  0x00000000004fe6cd in saveReport(Graph const&, Graph&, Alignment const&, MeasureCombination const&, Method*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) ()
#4  0x00000000004d06a7 in NormalMode::run(ArgumentParser&) ()
#5  0x000000000040a655 in main ()
(gdb)
```

So gdb does not let me see where exactly the segfault occurred. Any reason for this?

Comment: Could be many reasons. Could be that whatever bug is responsible for the segfault has also screwed up the stack to such an extent that `gdb` can't make sense of it.

Comment: Try the `bt` command to get a backtrace. It probably won't give much more but if what it give you is utter nonsense, odds are good the stack is corrupted. Narrows down

Comment: @Varshavchik wow I didn't even know that a segfault could screw up the stack in that way.

Comment: @user4581301 it wasn't utter nonsense. I got a trace that made sense.

Comment: The segfault won't screw up the stack. The segfault is the result of the stack being screwed up. OK so the trace made sense. Worth adding it to the question if you haven't already interpreted it and answered your own question.

Comment: @user4581301 still haven't figured it out. I've added the trace to the question.

Comment: Wondering if you have some reduced debugging output going. Can you turn off the optimizer (`-O0`) and crank up the debugger output any further  (`-g3`)? If not, you at least know where which function to drop a breakpoint on and start stepping.

Comment: @user4581301 adding those flags made no difference. When I set the breakpoint to that function and step then use "frame" again, it just gives me the function again (NodeCorrectness).

Comment: I'm out of ideas. It looks like something is being built wrong or gdb is configured to look in the wrong place. Last thing I can think of is posting your command line, makefile or whatever you're using to automate the build. Maybe someone will spot it